# Coloured rectangular Box of varying Size

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to draw a rectangular Box of golden colour in which I want textview and Upload image box in which data will be added in the next activity so it should vary with respect to the data in it
as shown in the two pics whose link shared below
Please Help.

Images:

[link-1 http://cdn7.staztic.com/app/a/2256/2256036/muthoot-fincorp-my-jewel-box-4103-1-s-307x512.jpg](http://cdn7.staztic.com/app/a/2256/2256036/muthoot-fincorp-my-jewel-box-4103-1-s-307x512.jpg)
[link-2 http://cdn8.staztic.com/app/a/2256/2256036/muthoot-fincorp-my-jewel-box-4103-3-s-307x512.jpg](http://cdn8.staztic.com/app/a/2256/2256036/muthoot-fincorp-my-jewel-box-4103-3-s-307x512.jpg)

Comment: thanks Simon i am not allowed to post images.thanks

Comment: No worries, they really should add a way for new users to do that...